# Convert UsbFile to Java type File

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio, ftp

I am using `libaums` and I read file from USB. All files as a `UsbFile` type. I want send my file to FTP. When I send FTP need use `FileInputStream` ant thos have parameter `File`. How can I convert?

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `FileInputStream` and not any `InputStream`?

Comment: All example to send FTP use FileInputStream

Comment: Check the documentation of whatever ftp library you are using. You don't have to do what all the examples do.

Comment: This question looks suspiciously similar another question posted just few hours ago using a different account:  [“UsbFile” convert to “File”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57963371/850848).

Comment: But there is not answer also

Comment: When answer somewhere I will flag one

Answer (score 1):

I think I answered this now a couple of times, at different places. There is simply no way to "convert" a `UsbFile` into a `java.io.File`. They are just completely different things. What you want to do is to use the `UsbFileInputStream`. Your FTP library (whichever it is..) should be able to handle a generic `InputStream` instead of only `FileInputStreams`.

Comment: Try : `InputStream in = new UsbFileInputStream(UsbFile);`